# Is it necessary to write OUTER JOINs multiple levels deep?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The database I'm working against has a top level table for Customers that then has child tables for related customer information, things like: addresses, phone numbers, emails etc. For some reason the way they designed the schema was to have many-to-many's for all these relationships that they've resolved with junction tables, for example, for address information:

| CustomerId | CustomerName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Freedy Krueger |
| 2 | Jason Voorhees |
| 3 | Michael Myers |

| CustomerId | AddressId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 3 | 30 |

| AddressId | Address1 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 123 Elm St, Springwood, OH |
| 11 | 456 Elm St, Springwood, OH |
| 30 | 666 Main St, Haddonfield, IL |

If I want to join Customer to all its children while still including records that do not have a child (e.g. CustomerId=2 has no address in this example) is it sufficient to LEFT OUTER JOIN on CustomerAddress? Or do I need to continue the LEFT OUTER JOINS as deep as the hierarchy goes (in this case also having a LEFT OUTER JOIN from CustomerAddress to Address as well)?

Hope that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: I see no reason why you would need an outer join going from customer address to address unless you think the data is jacked up.   Why not just write a left outer join from customer address to address to see if you get any customer address records that don't find a address.  You can just outer join on the key and then add another condition where address.addressid is null.  If you don't get any fallout you can be confident that an inner join would work.

Comment: If you include multiple many-side tables in query, I expect you will not like the result. If Customer 1 has 2 address records and 2 phone records, query will show 4 records for Customer 1.

Comment: Can you specify the expected result too. A [mcve].

Comment: @June7 Not what I asked

Comment: Desired results are always important for clarity.

Comment: And that's why it is a comment, not an answer. Still something to consider when evaluating the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CA.CUSTOMERID, CA.ADDRESSID
FROM CUSTOMERADDRESS AS CA
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS AS A
    ON CA.ADDRESSID = A.ADDRESSID
WHERE A.ADDRESSID IS NULL
```

This should tell you if there are any misses.  If you don't have any I would assume moving forward you would be safe with the inner join from customer address to address.